# How to show count of related foreign key objects in list_filter in Django Admin?

Tags: django, filter

I have to override the default Django admin `list_filter` to show the count of foreign key objects inside brackets, in the right hand side filters.

[image]

I am able to do it for a specific filter, using the following code, but how **do I create a Mixin or a class which can apply the same logic to all `fields` in `list_filter`?**

```
class ClientCountInFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    title = _('Client')
    parameter_name = 'client'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        qs = model_admin.get_queryset(request)

        for pk, name, count in qs.values_list('client__id','client__name').annotate(total=Count('client')).order_by('-total'):
            if count:
                yield (pk, f'{name} ({count})')

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        id_val = self.value()
        if id_val:
            return queryset.filter(client=id_val)

class CaseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = (ClientCountInFilter)
```

Comment: The field **`count`** can be either a model field/annotated field or *a queryset count*. In which case you are trying to implement?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu `count` is the variable containing the count of associated foreign keys.  It is defined in the foor loop `for pk, name, count in qs.values_list(..`